# Adapter notfiyDataSetChanged not working in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to add items to my list view when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page. I am trying to add items to the array in an AsyncTask then use notifyDataSetChanged on the existing adapter to display the new items, but it doesn't seem to work. However, it does work if I create a new adapter after adding the items, but this causes a jump to the top of the list, and is also probably bad practice?
Any ideas what I am doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.list_footer, 
            null, false);
    this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);

    items.add(new HomeListItem(1, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test), "Item Description Here",
            testImages));
    items.add(new HomeListItem(2, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test), "Item Description Here",
            testImages));
    items.add(new HomeListItem(3, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test), "Item Description Here",
            testImages));
    items.add(new HomeListItem(4, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test), "Item Description Here",
            testImages));
    items.add(new HomeListItem(5, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test), "Item Description Here",
            testImages));


    //Populate list view with array objects
    adapter = new HomeListItemAdapter(getActivity(), 1, items);

    listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(this);

}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    int lastInScreen = (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount);
    if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {

        new addItem().execute();

    }
}
private class addItem extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        loadingMore = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void arg3) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ADD ITEM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        //setListAdapter(new HomeListItemAdapter(getActivity(), 1, items));

        loadingMore = false;
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            items.add(new HomeListItem((items.size()+i), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo), "NEW ITEM " + (i),
                    testImages));
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

// Custom list item class for menu items

```
public class HomeListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HomeListItem> {

private List<HomeListItem> items;
private Context context;
private int numItems = 0;
private ImageView image1;
private ImageView image2;
private ImageView image3;


static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView sourceImage;
    TextView itemName;
    ImageView itemImage1;
    ImageView itemImage2;
    ImageView itemImage3;
    ImageView itemImage4;
    ImageView itemImage5;
}
public HomeListItemAdapter(Context context, int id, List<HomeListItem> items) {
    super(context, id, items);
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
    this.numItems = items.size();
}


public int getCount() {
    return numItems;
}

public HomeListItem getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return items.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        //Set up ViewHolder for item caching purposes
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.sourceImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.source_image);
        holder.itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
        holder.itemImage1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.itemImage2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image2);
        holder.itemImage3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image3);
        holder.itemImage4 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image4);
        holder.itemImage5 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image5);
        //Set holder tag
        convertView.setTag(holder);         
    } 
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Set item elements 
    holder.sourceImage.setImageDrawable(items.get(position).getSourcePic());
    holder.itemName.setText(items.get(position).getText());
    //Get ArrayList of item images
    ArrayList<Bitmap> itemImages = items.get(position).getItemImages();
    //Set ImageView bitmaps (Load in AsyncTask)
    holder.itemImage1.setImageBitmap(itemImages.get(0));
    holder.itemImage2.setImageBitmap(itemImages.get(1));
    holder.itemImage3.setImageBitmap(itemImages.get(2));
    holder.itemImage4.setImageBitmap(itemImages.get(3));
    holder.itemImage5.setImageBitmap(itemImages.get(4));


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: If I move to another fragment and go back, the items have been added. I don't understand why it's not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is not working, and if you want to debug it this not the answer. But if you need production ready solution for things like this you could use https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Answer (score 0):

the notify()-command tends to confuse. It has to be run from the Main-Thread. So either you call it there or you do some dirty hack and call it from the AsyncTask with:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    adapter.notify();
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    adapter.clear()//you using this one
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        items.add(new HomeListItem((items.size()+i), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo), "NEW ITEM " + (i),
                testImages));
    }
    return null;
}
```